# Redirecting scan for theme to error page

Tags: .htaccess

People are constantly scanning which theme I am using and every time I get mailed a 404 error.

The current structure is

```
http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/style.css
```

and I get requests like this

```
http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/bordeaux-theme/style.css
http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/radial-theme/style.css
http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/rockstar-theme/style.css
http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/tisa/themify/js/jquery.js
http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/simfo/themify/js/jquery.js
```

I am looking for way to redirect those requests to a, let's say, 418 error page with htaccess.

Any idea how?

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !themes/mytheme
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.css$
RewriteRule ^ /errors/teapot418.php [R=418,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (tisa|simfo).*\.js$
RewriteRule ^ /errors/teapot418.php [R=418,L]
```

So now only /themes/mytheme/style.css can be fetched for CSS.

Comment: No, not really, because these are just a few urls and I get maybe an hundred different urls.
So basically every url that needs something from my theme folder has to start with
     `http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/` and otherwise redirected to the 418 page.